# Yii test. Truncate foreign keys

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, phpunit

What is best solution for truncate database on each test start? I'm have InnoDB engine with foreigh keys, yii can't truncate table.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add a reference for **Yii2**  (as there are no easy to find examples):

```
$this->db->createCommand()->checkIntegrity(false)->execute();
$this->truncateTable('table_name');
$this->db->createCommand()->checkIntegrity(true)->execute();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you extend `CDbTestCase` and use the built in `public $fixtures` property to specify your fixture files, it will handle this automatically.

However, if you built your own fixture generating system, or otherwise want to truncate a table, you can use the following.

```
$this->getFixtureManager()->checkIntegrity(false);
$this->getFixtureManager()->truncateTable('table_name');
$this->getFixtureManager()->checkIntegrity(false);
```

This again assumes you are extends `CDbTestCase` for your unit test files. If you are not, then you can directly remove the integrity checks like so:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('set foreign_key_checks=0')->execute();
//do whatever, including truncating
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('set foreign_key_checks=1')->execute();
```

That will also temporarily disable the foreign key checks.

Answer (score 0):

Yii can truncate:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('TRUNCATE tbl_name')->execute();
```

Comment: Manualy, Yii can do it automaticly, but if some tables have foreign keys its not truncate.

Comment: so you need to address the foreign keys first!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Fixture support in Yii for your tests it will handle that for you automatically ...